# SQL Query WHERE CLAUSE is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to get some price records from my database. If you look at the records you will find 1 unexpected row (4th row) in the result set according to the query. Am I running the query right or I have to change it to eliminate the unexpected row (row number 4)?

```
     mysql> SELECT m.shop,
       m.price,
       m.p3,
       m.ds,
       m.coupon_active AS cp,
       m.online AS ol,
       m.affiliate AS af,
       m.colors
FROM shop_product_m2m m
LEFT JOIN shop s ON s.id=m.shop
WHERE product = 1971
  AND s.is_active = 1
  AND m.price IS NOT NULL
  AND m.price != ''
  AND (
       (m.p3=1 AND m.colors IS NOT NULL)
       OR 
       (m.ds =0 AND m.coupon_active=0 AND m.affiliate=0 AND m.online=0)
      )
ORDER BY m.p3 DESC,
         m.price ASC,
         m.modified DESC;
```

The output:

```
       +------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+
       | shop | price   | p3 | ds | cp | ol | af | colors      |
       +------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+
       |  317 | 8350.00 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | black       |
       |  268 | 8490.00 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | Black,White |
       |  192 | 8490.00 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | White,Black |
       |   38 | 8490.00 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  166 | 8110.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  160 | 8250.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  184 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  182 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  181 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  112 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |   90 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  130 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |   68 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |   66 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  150 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |   91 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  124 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  151 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       |  159 | 8490.00 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
       +------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+                                                                  
       19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That 4th row is not what I expected! It should not be in my result set:

```
       |   38 | 8490.00 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | NULL        |
```

EDIT For who wanted to see the CREATE TABLE:

```
     CREATE TABLE `shop_product_m2m` (
         `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `created` datetime NOT NULL,
         `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
         `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
         `shop` int(11) NOT NULL,
         `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
         `price` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
         `instock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
         `expired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `burgainable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
         `coupon_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `referral_url` text,
         `p3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `warrantytype` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
         `warranty` text,
         `colors` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
         `ds` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `affiliate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `http_status` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
         `color_varies` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         `price_variance_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          UNIQUE KEY `shop_2` (`shop`,`product`),
          KEY `shop` (`shop`),
          KEY `product` (`product`),
          CONSTRAINT `shop_product_m2m_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`shop`) 
          REFERENCES `shop` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `shop_product_m2m_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product`) 
          REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: why do you except it to not apear? `(m.ds =0 and m.coupon_active=0 and 
m.affiliate=0 and m.online=0)` seems to be true, connected with the or this will be in the result

Comment: Storing colors as comma separated list is not the best idea.

Comment: while its difficult to give an exact answer without sample data, try changing `AND (m.p3=1 AND m.colors 
       IS NOT NULL) OR (m.ds =0 and m.coupon_active=0 and 
       m.affiliate=0 and m.online=0)` to `AND ((m.p3=1 AND m.colors 
       IS NOT NULL) OR (m.ds =0 and m.coupon_active=0 and 
       m.affiliate=0 and m.online=0))`

Comment: In addition, your GROUP BY clause is meaningless and misleading in this query

Comment: When `LEFT JOIN` you usually have the right side table conditions in the `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` behavior. (When in `WHERE` clause, you get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)

Comment: Please make clear which conditions belong together. You have mixed `AND`s and `OR`s at the same level, so the precedence of `AND` and `OR` come into play. Effectively, you have `WHERE (A AND B AND C AND D AND E) OR (F)`, where `F` is `m.ds =0
      AND m.coupon_active=0
      AND m.affiliate=0
      AND m.online=0` - since all of those conditions are true for the fourth row, that's why it's in the result.

Comment: Actually I had my code grouped when I posted this question but some expert edited it to more readable way sacrificing the grouping by parentheses! @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: It's still not clear why you believe that the fourth row should be excluded. Of the columns of data *we* are being shown, all conditions that we can evaluate seem to be true (aside from those in the first condition for the `OR`, but since it's an `OR` and everything to the right of it is true, we can ignore that). The columns we can't see (`product` and `is_active`), we can't comment on.

Answer (score 2):

```
(m.p3=1 AND m.colors IS NOT NULL) 
    OR 
(m.ds =0 and m.coupon_active=0 and m.affiliate=0 and m.online=0)
```

Your first condition is false BUT the second one is TRUE.
Your **OR** will be true

So it is normal to see the 4th row in the result set.

Try changing the query depending on the result you need.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with the query you need, just tell us what exactly you want with all the conditions (I don't really know if changing the OR to AND is what you expect, I guess no)

Comment: Actually I tried in many ways and could not eliminate the 4th row. That's why I am here for help from you guys. @Theo

Comment: Please notice that the two group conditions here are also enclosed in parentheses which someone had eliminated by editing the question.